# Getting Unhandled Runtime Error of "self is not defined"

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-hooks, server-side-rendering

In my Next js app,

Getting Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: self is not defined

community/[title]/page.js:

```
"use server";
import Subpage from './subpage.js';

export default async function page({ params }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Subpage params={params} /> //Client side component with hooks
        </div>
    )
}
```

If i add `"use client";` instead of `"use server";`
It's working, but i want to fetch some data in page.js with server-side action

Also i am not able to make Subpage client side because i want to use hooks too and my code is also perfectly working along with "self is not defined" error.

In subpage i am using a lot things with CKEditor too

I want solution how to remove "self error" without removing `"use server";` and without making subpage serverside.